# View hot questions of past months?

Tags: feature-request, support, hot-questions

I like to see the hot questions of the month because are great questions. There is a way to view the hot questions of past months? If not, I think this will be a cool option.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of such a feature within StackExchange itself. However, there are 3rd party sites that scrape the site for this information.

The best one I know of is: http://stackmonthly.com/

That one seems to be missing some of the top questions. But nevertheless it's still good.