# Search the top posts for the day/week/month/year

Tags: feature-request, search, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View hot questions of past months?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127605/view-hot-questions-of-past-months)

Under questions we can click on "votes" and see a list of the top voted questions of all time.  At some point, most frequent users will look through many of the questions there.  For the most part the list does not change over time, so there is no reason to return.  (unless you are looking for a specific post)

I often find myself wanting see the most voted questions for the month or the week, and I think it would be helpful if after clicking on "votes" in the "Questions" tab, one could further limit the search by click on either "this week", "this month" or "this year".

**Request:** I think having *some* method to search based on **the time period** in which the question was asked would be very helpful.  There does not seem to be a way even if one uses the [advanced search.](https://stackoverflow.com/search)